# Freshly setup Qt build for Android fails on OSX machine

Tags: android, qt, android-studio, qtandroidextras

I am doing a fresh installation of `Commercial Qt` on a new `MacOS Sierra` machine. I am trying to build a sample Qt app for `android` & `iOS`. I am able to build my QtApp for iOS without any trouble.

**But on android I get the following error:**

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
19:47:50: The process "/Users/MyComputer/Qt/5.7/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project t1 (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.7.1))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
```

I have downloaded latest `ndk r14b` from [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html).

I have installed latest sdk that comes with Android Studio these days from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html). And updated `android sdkmanager` to installed all platforms ranging from `android-19` to `android-25`.

I have installed latest JDK 8 as well. I tested the android setup by building & running an android app from Android Studio which worked flawlessly.

**Qt worked with Android pretty nicely. What has changed ? Should I do some tweaks because of some structural changes in Android ?**

Copying `PathToAndroidStudio/templates` into `PathToAndroidSDK/templates` or `PathToAndroidSDK/tools/templates` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754878/qt-creator-wont-list-any-available-android-build-sdks/42811774#42811774) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721945/building-android-projects-in-qt-doesnt-work-anymore) **doesn't seem to be enough**.

*What more should I do apart from copying the `templates` folder as suggested in some other answers ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use Ant build system. Change it to using Gradle-based one or take a look here: [The ant/ folder is suddenly missing from Android SDK. Did Google remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912824/ant-folder-missing-from-android-sdk/42921645#42921645)

[image: edit project build settings]

Comment: ok great. to build with ant, I just copied the ant from the zip provided in question your refered & placed it my tools folder. thats it. ant build successful. gradle build has been working for me. I wanted to figure the reason behind why ant had stopped working. thanks for the answer.